# Configuring PyDev

Tags: python, setup

After speeding too much time trying to find out what went wrong with the installation of a new module in python, I realised that the root of the problem is due to fault configuration of PyDev plug-in. On the contrary, the same module works fine in IDLE 3.2. So my question is: how could I configure PyDev with exactly the same settings as IDLE 3.2???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but I'll leave the answer anyway (just in case someone else comes across the same problem - like I did a few days ago).

From this tutorial:

> To configure the interpreter:
>   1. Go to: **window > preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - (Python/Jython/IronPython)**.
>   Note that the **Auto Config** will try to find it in your PATH, but it can fail if it's not there (or if you want to configure a different interpreter).
>   On **Windows** it'll also search the registry and provide a choice based on the multiple interpreters available in your computer (searching in the registry).
>   On **Linux/Mac**, usually you can do a 'which python' to know where the python executable is located.
>   2. Choose the interpreter you have installed in your computer (such as python.exe, jython.jar or ipy.exe).
>   3. Select the paths that will be in your **SYSTEM PYTHONPATH**.
>   **IMPORTANT:** Select only folders that will NOT be used as source folders for any project of yours 
>   (those should be later configured as source folders in the project).
>   
>   **IMPORTANT for Mac users:** The Python version that usually ships with Mac doesn't seem to have the .py source files 
>   available, which are required for PyDev, so, using a different interpreter is recommended (i.e.: Download it from http://python.org). If you don't want to use a different interpreter, get the source files for the Python '/Lib' folder
>   and add those to the system installation.